# Automatic package distribution system Windows

Tags: windows, packages, software-distribution

I have built a Windows-only desktop application which is composed of two main executables and various configuration files. 
The two applications are developed in different languages (JS and C++, respectively) and should always be in sync with versions (ie. appA-v1.0.exe would probably be incompatible with appB-v2.0.exe).

I'm looking for an auto update method that helps me ensure this constraint is always true: this would mean **distributing a single package containing both applications** instead of using language-specific auto-updaters (I used Sparkle for C++ and Squirrel for electron in the past).

I have full access to the machines this software would be installed on (5/6, all managed by us), so the idea is to have a timed update check that in case of need downloads and unpacks the update. The update should **not require user interaction**.

I could write this on my own, using an FTP server to host the package, checking last modification date, downloading and unpacking if needed, but I was wondering if there are better solutions.. any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a software development question, it is a system administrators question, it would be the same question if someone else handed you over a bunch of ready-make exe and dll files. And the canonical answer is: put all your files into an MSI package, and use [MSI deployment](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html) for distribution (or, whatever standard mechanism is used in your company for distribution of other software).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on ServerFault.SE

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: This is a development question in a sense that no package is yet prepared and packaging is not really an administrative task. Still, more suited for SO.

Comment: ServerFault? This is a resource request.

Comment: @docbrown - disagree, while "use whatever your sysadmin uses to distribute applications" is a valid answer, there are other solutions not normally available to a sysadmin e.g. adding automatic updates to your applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question is still generating activity, I'll add my solution so it will no longer appear as opened.

I simply ended up setting up a git repository containing all the compiled assets (for both applications).

I added a deployment key to that repo for each machine I had to update, and added a cronjob that simply executed a `git pull` every night at 1 AM. When an update is to be released, I simply push to the right branch of that repo and wait for it to be pulled.

---

While this may not seem an optimal solution to the problem, I went with this one for a number of reasons:

- Simplicity in setup

  - this point is mostly thanks to the small number of machines to be updated
- Unique package distribution (the 2 applications are always synced with versions)
- No extra code to be added in any of the applications
- Relying on an already paid "hosting service" (i.e. bitbucket)
- Pull update logic (the machines have huge limitations when it comes to incoming connections, due to company firewall policy)

Of course this is not ideal for a bunch of reasons:

- No way to control if the update has been applied
- No way to force an update outside scheduled update times

---

Again, I don't know if this could be *ever* useful to anyone, it was a particularly specific case with a lot of constraints by the machine owners, so please don't throw at me too much hate for having used this solution.

Comment: @Aliester originally mentioned this as a possible solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way you could handle this is by using extensions to the WSUS (Windows services update server?) to deploy updates to your application.

This answer from Microsoft is a little old but I think it still
applies:

> Hi Ahmed Shariff, to Patch third party software like Adobe Reader,
>   Flash player, Java and other you have the choice between :
>        - Free Applications (open source) :
>             - Local Update Publisher (http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net/fr/index.html)
>             - Wsus Package Publisher (http://wsuspackagepublisher.codeplex.com/)
>        - Commercial Applications :
>             - Patch Manager from Solarwinds (http://www.solarwinds.com/solutions/microsoft-wsus-patch-management.aspx)
>             - Corporate Software Inspector from Secunia (http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/corporate/help/sfw.csiwsusconfiguration/)

Source:  [Microsoft Help Forum Post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/67833919-6477-41ee-9c8f-1cdd34b9641e/using-wsus-v30-to-install-3rd-party-software?forum=winserverwsus)

Alternatively if your application is portable (no installer necessary) you could use a git server to host your binary and add a scheduled task which pulls from your repository.  It isn't exactly what it was built for but you do you get versioning out of the box and easy rollback capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a domain, investigate using the SCCM mechanism.  This system allows you to schedule and push out SW updates, etc and can distribute and install silently and remotely.  It's a large domain to study but it does do what you ask for.